# The system cannot find the file specified: libmsvcr90.def

Tags: python, python-2.7, f2py

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://notmatthancock.github.io/2017/02/10/calling-fortran-from-python.html.
It goes over how to execute Fortran code in python via f2py. However, when I run the program with:

```
f2py -c -m my_lib my_lib.f90
```

It outputs this:

```
> (Python_ver_2.7)
> C:\Users\Robert\Documents\18650_Aluminum_Cell\Testcode>call
> "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\Scripts\\..\python.exe"
> "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\Scripts\\f2py.py" -c -m
> my_lib my_lib.f90 running build running config_cc unifing config_cc,
> config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext,
> build commands --fcompiler options running build_src build_src
> building extension "my_lib" sources f2py options: [] f2py:>
> c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7\my_libmodule.c
> creating
> c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7 Reading
> fortran codes...
>         Reading file 'my_lib.f90' (format:free) Line #11 in my_lib.f90:"          intent(hide), depend(image) :: n = shape(image,
> 0)"
>         analyzeline: cannot handle multiple attributes without type specification. Ignoring ' depend(image)'. Post-processing...
>         Block: my_lib
>                         Block: threshold_image Post-processing (stage 2)... Building modules...
>         Building module "my_lib"...
>                 Constructing wrapper function "threshold_image"...
>                   output = threshold_image(image,threshold)
>         Wrote C/API module "my_lib" to file "c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7\my_libmodule.c"
> adding
> 'c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c'
> to sources.   adding
> 'c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7' to
> include_dirs. copying
> C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c
> -> c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7 copying
> C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h
> -> c:\users\robert\appdata\local\temp\tmphgtm23\src.win-amd64-2.7 build_src: building npy-pkg config files running build_ext Building
> msvcr library:
> "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\libs\libmsvcr90.a"
> (from
> C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5054_none_08e4d1f3a83cf865\msvcr90.dll)
> objdump.exe:
> C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.5054_none_08e4d1f3a83cf865\msvcr90.dll:
> File format not recognized dlltool: Can't open def file:
> C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\libs\libmsvcr90.def
> error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
> 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Python_ver_2.7\\libs\\libmsvcr90.def'
```

I have a file named libmsvcr90.dll.a, but nothing else that resembles this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the file from and placing it on 'C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\envs\Python_ver_2.7\libs\' directory.

https://github.com/ppy/osu-wine/blob/master/osu!.app/Contents/Frameworks/wswine.bundle/lib/wine/libmsvcr90.def